# Have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer E-15. The InsydeH2O BIOS cannot be adjusted in anyway to enable virtualization

Tags: bios, virtualization

My Acer E-15 E-5 -523-979H laptop with and AMD A9 7th gen. processor came with Windows 10 Home installed. It always operated very slowly and would not run 64 bit programs even though it clearly has a 64 bit processor. I eliminated windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 18.04 and now the system runs a lot faster but I still have the problem with virtualization. Running lscpu confirms the existence of a 64 bit processor, but I still cannot get programs like Virtualbox to work because virtualization is not enabled in BIOS and there is no way to change this in the BIOS itself through the menu structure which comes up during boot. I have searched in many locations to try and fix this issue. Any help on fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is an updated BIOS for your device?

Comment: There is a higher bios available but I cannot install it because the file is made for Windows. Is there a way to set the bios using some program under linux? The processor is capable of running  at 64 bit but I cannot change any setting in the bios on boot that enables virtualization.